# The right word order in sentence with what is

Tags: word-order

I have the following three sentences:

> 1/ We will show what is the relation of this parameter to other
>   existing properties.
>
> 2/ We will show what the relation of this parameter is to other
>   existing properties.
>
> 3/ We will show what the relation of this parameter to other existing
>   properties is.

I think that 2 is wrong. I strongly prefer 1/ but I do not know if it is correct. 3 is surely correct but it sounds cumbersome.

Comment: The two words "what is" juxtaposed is always a question, so 1 must be wrong. I prefer 2. I think this question is best answered on ELL.

Comment: That best option might be to leave out those two words altogether: _We will show the relation of this parameter to other existing properties_.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: no, 1 and 2 are licensed by extraposition.

Comment: @ColinFine It may be "licensed" but I think in that case it should at least be mentioned that it is stilted to the point of inadmissibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All are grammatical.

3) is the form given by the normal rule of inversion; but is very awkward.

The other two are both allowed by [heavy clause extraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition). I find 2) to be the clearest.

Answer (score 0):

When showing someone something, "what is" is implied in the showing.  No need to specifically indicate it.

> "We will show the relation[ship] of this parameter to other existing parameters."